# Proving $||Tx-Ty||\leq C||x-y||^2$

Tags: proof-writing, normed-spaces

If $||x||$ is the euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R^d}$ how can I prove all linear transformations $T:\mathbb{R^d}\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R^d}}$ which satisfy $$||Tx-Ty||\leq C||x-y||^2$$, $x,y\in \mathbb{R^d}$ for a constant C, are constant?

Comment: I don't know how to formalize it, but I think the fact that $$\lim_{x\to y}\frac{||Tx-Ty||}{||x-y||}\leq \lim_{x\to y}c||x-y|| = 0$$ means the "derivative" is 0, so $T$ must be constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is linear, $T(u)=0$. Let $x$ be an element with $\|x\|=1$,  and $u>0$ $\|T(ux)-T(0)\|=u\|T(x)\|\leq C\|ux\|^2=u^2C$. This implies that $\|T(x)\|\leq uC$ for every $u>0$, we deduce that $\|T(x)\|=0$.

Comment: I understand this works with $||x||=1$ but how can you assure it works for  $||x||\neq 1$?

Comment: Then $T({x\over\|x\|})=0$ implies that $T(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $T$ is not constant; that is, for some $x\neq y$, $T(x) \neq T(y)$. Then $\|T(x)-T(y)\| = \|T(x-y)\| \neq 0$.

Without loss of generality, assume $\|T(x-y)\| = \alpha$.  and $\|x-y\| = \beta$. Then for any scalar $\gamma > 0$, the claim that

$$ \|Tx-Ty\| \leq C\|x-y\|^2$$

$$ \iff \gamma\|Tx-Ty\| = \|T(x-y)\gamma\| \leq C \|(x-y)\gamma\|_2^2 = C\gamma^2 \|x-y\|^2$$

$$\iff \gamma \alpha \leq C \gamma^2 \beta$$

$$\iff \alpha \leq C \gamma \beta$$

since $\gamma > 0$.

Recall this has to hold for ALL $\gamma > 0$. So, picking $\gamma$ small enough ($\gamma < \alpha / (C\beta)$) provides the necessary counterexample.

Therefore $T$ must be constant.

(Additional note: The condition $\gamma > 0$ and the ability to divide by $\beta$ only works if $\alpha>0, \beta > 0$. If $T$ is constant, then this analysis breaks down to $0 \leq 0$ for all $\gamma$ which is certainly true.)